# All possible subsequences converging to same function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $S = \{f_{n}\}$ be a sequence of continuous functions on a compact set $K \subset \mathbb{R}$. Furthermore suppose $S$ is a compact subset of $C(K)$ (the set of continuous functions on $K$ with the metric on $C(K)$ being the sup norm). If every subsequence of $S$ converges uniformly to the same function $f$, then must $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ uniformly?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the confusion. $(f_n)$ is a sequence in $S$, so by assumption it converges uniformly to $f$.

Comment: Also are you sure you mean the sequence $S$ is _itself_ a compact subset of a function space? Seems rather unlikely.

Comment: But yes, a sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ if and only if every subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ converges to $x$.

Comment: Did you really ask what you wanted to ask? Didnt you mean: "if every *convergent* subsequence of $(f_n)$ converges to the same function $f$, then the whole sequence $(f_n)$ converges to $f$"?